# http request metodo post ionic 2, angular 2

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estou fazendo uma requisição post http, porém sem sucesso...

Na verdade tenho um sucesso no cabeçalho o mesmo retorna, porém o body não está rolando.

Meu código está assim:

```
          postRequest() {
          let myHeader = new Headers({

        "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",


       });
        let options = new RequestOptions({
          headers: myHeader

        });
        let body = JSON.stringify({

          key: "versao" , value:"1.1"


        });
```

No body eu preciso de um request Body com a key e value para retornar a consulta feita no webservice.

Vi em alguns sites que dizem que o body tem que ser escrito no formato "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

poderiam ajudar ?

Answer (score 0):

Ronald. Você está fazendo um POST mas não está enviando nenhum dado ao servidor. Logo abaixo, você diz que quer fazer uma consulta no web-service, certo? Para isso, o método correto é o GET.
Ficaria algo assim:

```
getRequest(): Observable<Response>{
        let myUrl = "http://www.google.com"; //sua url de acesso
        let myHeader = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}); // JSON!
        let options = new RequestOptions({headers: myHeader});
        let body = JSON.stringify({
          key: "versao" , value:"1.1"
        });

      return this.http.get(myUrl, body).map(this.handleData);
       // chama a função abaixo
}

private handleData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.text();
  if (body) {
    return body.data;
  } else {
    return {};
  }
}
```